# Why does i say my function doesnt exist even thought the function was created?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have to create a Function to Calculate invoiceID,InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal.  So I created a function named fnNetOwed.I have to run it in this syntax:

```
Select invoiceId, dbo.fnNetOwed(invoiceid) from invoices
Where dbo.fnNetOwed (invoiceid) >0
```

And get the same results as if I did

```
 Select invoiceID,InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal From     Invoices 
Where InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal>0
```

This is my code for creating it:
    CREATE FUNCTION fnNetOwed
    (@GetInvoiceId Money)
    RETURNS Int

```
BEGIN
RETURN     (SELECT (InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) AS 'OWED'
        FROM Invoices
        WHERE @GetInvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID);
END 
GO
```

This is what i am using to call it/execute:
    Select InvoiceId, fnNetOwed(98) from Invoices
    Where fnNetOwed(98) >0;
This is the ERROR I get when i run it:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'fnNetOwed' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Thanks i tried both using schmia didn't work but dbo did bu something is wrong in my math or variable placement. case it returning all the invoice ids with the same total. any ideas on that. @Khaled,@Raymer Ortiz

Answer (score 1):

Try to call it using your schema name : `SELECT schema.fnNetOwed(98)`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server scalar user defined functions must be called using 2 part names. You will see this error if you attempt to call the functions using a 1 part name. Can you check if that is the problem ?

So if your function name is "function1" and is defined in the dbo schema, then instead of

"select function1()" you should call it as "select dbo.function1()"